# What does the 'B' (or bonus) mean on a basketball scoreboard?

Tags: rules, terminology, basketball

I was looking at pictures of scoreboards today, and I noticed that some of them have 'B's on the boards:
[image: A basketball scoreboard with two 'B's and the lights next to them with freehand circles encircling them]
[image: A basketball scoreboard with two 'B's on the left and corresponding spaces on the right for them with freehand circles encircling them all]

The same thing appears on NBA games, often in the broadcast scoreboard as well:
[image: NBA broadcast scoreboard showing bonus too]

I've never noticed those before. What do they mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's a bonus marker.

A team who commits 7 fouls gives the other team a bonus - which gives a free throw with every foul from that point on.

The second B on the second image indicate that a team has reached 10 fouls (in HS and college this is the double bonus and means that you shoot 2 foul shots from there forward instead of 1 and 1)